# How to read array in jade file node.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, express

I have this array set from my route to view

```
[ 'dgdgd',
  'gdgdfg',
  'gdgd',
  'dgdg',
  'gdfdg',
  'gdg']
```

In my jade file I wrote

```
select#e1.col-md-12.getDb(name='dbname')
    option
    for myset, i in data
        option #{myset}
```

I am completely new to jade. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use jade syntax from [here](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html)

```
select#e1.col-md-12.getDb(name='dbname')
    option
  each val, index in data
    option=val
```